# Status bar style in NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to reproduce the effect seen on first page here: https://github.com/sebawita/starships, where there is a status bar with light content and no action bar.

I have been trying the instructions specified here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1779#issuecomment-522586849

I'm working with NativeScript Vue rather than angular, but I don't suppose it matters. Here is my component code:

```xml
<template>
    <Page
        class="page"
        ref="page"
        statusBarStyle="light"
        @loaded="onPageLoaded()">
        <GridLayout rows="*, 60, 60, 20, 60, *">
            <Label row="0" textWrap="true" class="header" text="Starship Service" />
            <TextField
                id="emailField"
                hint="Email"
                keyboardType="email"
                returnKeyType="next"
                autocorrect="false"
                row="1"
                class="textfield"
                ios.clearButtonMode="1"
                ref="field1" />

            <TextField
                row="2"
                secure="true"
                hint="Password"
                returnKeyType="send"
                class="textfield" />
            <Button row="4" text="Log in" />
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { topmost } from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";

export default {
    methods: {
        onPageLoaded: function(args) {
            console.log('page loaded');

            if (isIOS) {
                Object.defineProperty(UIViewController.prototype, 'preferredStatusBarStyle', {
                    get: function () {
                        return this._preferredStatusBarStyle || UIStatusBarStyle.Default;
                    },
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                });
                let controller = topmost().ios.controller;
                controller._preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default;
                controller.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
            }

            console.log("page loaded done");
        },
    },
    computed: {
        message() {
            return "Welcome to the first version of the starship app :-)";
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<style scoped lang="scss">
    .page {
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sebawita/starships/master/icons/space-bg.jpg?raw=true");
        color: #fff; 
    }
</style>
```

I have this in my `Info.plist` file:

```
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

Comment: You are suppose to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `true` as you want to change your status bar appearance per controller.

Comment: Good point. However, changing ```<false/>``` to ```<true/>``` unfortunately doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may natively set the status bar style on your page loaded events

**HTML**

```
<Page class="page" @loaded="onPageLoaded">
```

**JS**

```
onPageLoaded: function(args) {
  let controller = args.object.frame.ios.controller;
  controller.navigationBar.barStyle = 0; // `0` for Black or `1` for Light
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contribution. That method works for me if I have an action bar. However, if I remove the action bar, then it doesn't.

This finding is in line with the documentation here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/change-status-bar-style-ios.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick solution, you could set the view controller based appearance to false and set the stausbar style on shared application instance while loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide the action bar for each component.

```
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page/page';

constructor(
      private page: Page) {
      page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if the action bar is hidden, the ability to programmatically set the status bar style is lost. I **could** give it a zero height, but that comes with its own set of issues (see the github issue tracker link).

Answer (score 0):

Like was answered in another comment, you need to make sure your `Info.plist` file has this entry:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

The crucial bit of code needed was added in either NativeScript 6.4 or 6.5 here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/8241/files

This the iOS `preferredStatusBarStyle()` function on the NativeScript Page object.  NativeScript-Vue exposes this as a prop that you can pass in 'light' or 'dark' values to.  See the updated [Vue documentation](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/page/).